# Is Google Cloud Platform documentation available for offline reading?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking for eReader and PDF formats of the Google Cloud Platform documentation and whitepapers. Right now I cannot find anything similar to how AWS provides documentation in PDF and Kindle formats.
It would be great to have docs in a way that can be read without an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Google’s Documentation changes so often that having a static document may not be a good option. If you really want to you can select the text that you want to read , copy it to a Google Doc and then select the Download menu option and file type (i.e. PDF). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Derek Fender, that is useful.